# android - RelativeLayout height to fill remaining space of CollapsingToolBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have the following design where there is a CollapsingToolbarLayout on top and below there is a RelativeLayout:

[image]

I want the RelativeLayout to fill the remaining space until bottom so I can center  the content like this:

[image]

I tried using **match_parent** on the RelativeLayout but it takes the size of the whole root layout, including the CollapsingToolbarLayout:

[image]

What can I do? This is the complete layout's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".UserActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/activity_user_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout android:id="@+id/activity_user_collapsingtoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/activity_user_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <!-- toolbar content -->

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/activity_user_eventsalert"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar_remove_titlegray_48px"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="No events yet"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTitleGray"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_bottom_white_to_transparent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried running the app or just using that preview? Because the code looks correct assuming your string resource is set up properly for the RelativeLayout's behavior

Comment: Which is the correct one? _match_parent_ or _wrap_content_? @darnmason

Comment: Match parent...

Comment: Can you specify your problem in more detail? It seems your code is fine.

Comment: Are you using fragment to inflate this view , if this is the case would you check what is the height attribute for the host activity which is hosting this fragment

Answer (score 5):

Try Appbar Scroll listener

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    mAppBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

                  int appbarHeight=appBarLayout.getHeight(); // or measured height
                  int totalHeightOfDevice=height;
                  int absoluteHeight=height-appbarHeight;

                  // position your view to absolute height..
            }
        });
```

Comment: I feel absolutely dirty for using this... but this seems to be the only way to work around the quirkiness of the CoordinatorLayout. Works for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_user_eventsalert"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="No events yet"
            android:textColor=""
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That doesn't help. The problem is that the RelativeLayout is too large because of the match_parent.

Answer (score -1):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/activity_user_eventsalert"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar_remove_titlegray_48px"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="No events yet"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTitleGray"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams` doesn't have `layout_weight`.

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in the relative layout:

```
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams` doesn't have `layout_weight`.